# C function that receives pointer to 2 dimensional array of struct

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, declaration

I have this struct

```
typedef struct _cood{
    int x, y;
}coordirnate;
```

And in the main code, I have a `coordinate foo[3][3]`. I need to pass this `foo` as a pointer to the function `scanCood()`.

```
void scanCood(coordinates *foo[3][3]);
void printCood(coordinates foo[3][3]);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    coordinate foo[3][3];

    printf("WRITE YOUR NUMBERS:\n");
    scanCood(&foo);

    printf("PRINTING YOUR NUMBERS\n\n");
    printCood(foo);

    return (0);
}
```

The `scanCood` function is like this:

```
void scanCood(coordinate *foo[3][3]){

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

            scanf("%d", &foo[i][j]->x);
            scanf("%d", &foo[i][j]->y);

        }
    }
}
```

Printing is easy with `printCood`, and I had no problems with it, but the program core dumps on `scanCood` after I input 2 numbers.

The compiler gives these warnings, but doesn't impede from compiling:

[Compilation output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P0B0.png)

I need some help with how I should make this function with this pointer.

Comment: Did you actually read the warnings? Do you understand what they are saying?

Comment: Sincerely, I don't.

Comment: You are passing a wrong pointer type to scanCood. See @Vlad's answer.

Comment: The structure you show `typedef struct _cood { int x, y; } coordirnate;` is unrelated to the type you pass to the functions according to the prototypes (`void scanCood(coordinates *foo[3][3]);`) and the type you define them as taking (`void scanCood(coordinate *foo[3][3]){ … }`).  The names you've got are `coordirnate` vs `coordinates` vs `coordinate`.  C compilers are even less forgiving than me!  You have to be consistent in your spelling.  Use copy'n'paste to create questions on SO to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: Why don't you just use `void scanCood(coordinates foo[3][3]);`

Comment: Note that at this stage of your programming career, if the compiler deigns to warn you that there's a problem, it is telling you that there's a bug in your code.  In fact, it'll probably still be true in 30 years time — at least, that's how I regard the vast majority of compiler warnings (and I've been coding in C for more than 30 years).  Until you know enough to know when it is safe to ignore a warning, assume it isn't safe.

Comment: Also, please don't use images for text from compilers.  Include it directly in the question, treating it like code.

Comment: Sorry, i kinda new here.

Answer (score 2):

The function declaration is wrong.

I think you mean the following

```
void scanCood( coordinate ( *foo )[3], size_t n )
{
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            scanf("%d", &foo[i][j].x);
            scanf("%d", &foo[i][j].y);
        }
    }
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
scanCood( foo, 3 );
```

Used by you parameter declaration

```
coordinate * foo[3][3]
```

means a two dimensional array of pointers of type `coordinate *` that is adjusted to pointer of the following type

```
coordinate * ( *foo )[3]
```

If you wanted to pass a pointer to the array then the parameter should be declared like

```
    coordinate ( * foo )[3][3]
```

though there is no need to declare the parameter such a way.

In this case indeed the function is called like

```
scanCood(&foo);
```

However the body of the function should be rewritten using a correct syntax.
For example

```
void scanCood( coordinate ( *foo )[3][3] )
{
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            scanf("%d", &( *foo )[i][j].x);
            scanf("%d", &( *foo )[i][j].y);
        }
    }
}
```

Take into account that there are typos in the function declarations

```
void scanCood(coordinates *foo[3][3]);
                        ^
void printCood(coordinates foo[3][3]);
                         ^
```

Comment: This kinda worked, thanks